# Rails 4 - sending devise params to a User model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, parameters, nomethoderror

i have my own `RegistrationsController`, which inherits from Devise. In update I want to send `params` to my `User` method like above:

```
def update
   params = resource.delete_invoice(params) if resource.check_invoice(params[:user])
   if params[:user][:name].blank?
      flash[:alert] = t 'devise.registrations.wrong_user_name'
      redirect_to action: 'edit' and return
  end
  super
end
```

Unfortunatelly i get error:

```
NoMethodError in Users::RegistrationsController#update, undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

It's strange because I can normally write `puts params` and it's not empty. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
unless params[:user].blank?
  if params[:user][:name].blank?
    #do your stuff
  end
end
```

Comment: U missunderstood me. I got an error in first line when trying to call checkinvoice.

Answer (score 0):

The error here is that it is trying to call [] on a nil object, as it is very unlikely that params or flash is nil, the only other place you call [] is on params[:user] which suggests that this is nil.

Couple of options, check if params[:user] is nil or use try:

```
if params[:user].nil? or params[:user][:name].blank?
      flash[:alert] = t 'devise.registrations.wrong_user_name'
      redirect_to action: 'edit' and return
end
```

Alternatively:

```
if params[:user].try(:fetch, :name).try(:blank?)
      flash[:alert] = t 'devise.registrations.wrong_user_name'
      redirect_to action: 'edit' and return
end
```

Which I think is neater. NB try is a rails method, not ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the resource is built when you run update? In Rails 4 the `build_resource` is being built inside that method [devise/registrations_controller](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L41-L59). Probably you want to use `resource_class`?